# non empty array with length=0 in Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

```
const items = [];
Meteor.http.call("GET", url,function(error,result){  
  $.each(JSON.parse(result.content), function(key, value){
    items.push(value)
  });
});
```

Code below return non-empty array items with length 0. 
How can I iterate array or extract all values by key to an array?
[image]

Comment: Where does it return the array with length 0? Where are you logging `items` to get length 0?

Comment: console.log(items.length ) =0+ at screen you can see  "Array[0]"

Comment: Where are you logging it? If you're logging it outside of the Metor callback function, you might see that because the async function hasn't completed yet.

Comment: yes, i am logging it  outside of the Metor callback function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Meteor.http.call` is an asynchronous function with a callback. A quick way I can think to do what you want is the following:

```
const items = [];
Meteor.http.call("GET", url,function(error,result){  
  $.each(JSON.parse(result.content), function(key, value){
    items.push(value)
  });
  handleItems(items);
});

function handleItems(items) {
  console.log(items.length) // 1
  // Do what you want with the items array here.
}
```

Comment: yes, when code executing in callback all is ok. How i can taken outside callback array with original length ?

Comment: Most simply, you can't. You'll need to handle things in the callback because the code is async. Maybe if you tell me more context of what you are trying to achieve I can suggest something else?

Comment: i am trying fecth data from api(json data) and send it to Bar function(plot) from react-chartjs

Comment: Ok, so I would suggest you call this Meteor function in `componentDidMount`, then when you get the results, save the results in the component state (using `this.setState`).